# Install multiple apks android adb with rollback

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to install multiple apks in one command, I can achive that but If one fails I need to do a rollback of all applications.

adb install -r app1.apk & adb install -r app2.apk & adb install -r app3.apk

The aim is: Install all or not install nothing.

It is possible ?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean `rollback` of your applications?

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's just a question of scripting it. What scripting language would you prefer to do it in?

Comment: @JaredBurrows  Rollback means, If I have apk1 v 1.0 and I will try to install apk1. v2.0, If fails then I have to install apk1 v 1.0. If you use -r it is automatically in android.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the output of each single `adb install` command and look for the "Success" word. When an installation fails (missing "Success" word), proceed with an *uninstall-all* command (which you need to define by create a sequence of `adb uninstall <package_name>` commands)

Comment: the problem here is, I have a previous version I will delete all and I want to keep the original version. I have two apps (apk1.apk and apk2.apk). The apk1.apk v1 works fine with apk2.apk v1 and the apk1.apk v2 works fine with apk2.apk v2. For that I need to update all or not update nothing.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `monkeyrunner` (bundled with the Android SDK). It will handle the installation for you, detecting failure, and a python script something like this:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

apks = ['app1.apk', 'app2.apk', 'app3.apk']

#installPackage will return false if it fails
#use a generator to short circuit on failure
generator = (device.installPackage(apk) for apk in apks)

if not all(generator):
    device.removePackage(apk) for apk in apks
```

I didn't check that this compiles/runs, and it can be improved to only uninstall that which was successfully installed, but you get the point, hopefully.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this github page. you can install multiple apps automatically.
[Automatic installation of multiple apk files.](https://gist.github.com/hsanchez/2837606)